# How to say: work (in/at/on/?) your hours

Tags: verbs, prepositions

My intention is to let a person (i.e. my employee), whom I'm talking to, to choose his/her work hours.

For example:

Employee: *I'm going to do this task between 1-4 pm today.*

Me: *Sure, no problem. **Work (in/at/on/?) your hours!***

What preposition should I use?

Comment: None of the above.  I would say, "Work **your own** hours."

Answer (score 1):

To a native English's speaker ear, I don't think any of those (or any other preposition) would sound natural in that formulation. I would say "Sure, no problem. Work within whatever range of hours is suitable for you!".

Comment: “Choose your own hours” would be even more idiomatic.

Comment: If I were to use, I would say, ...work at your convenience;

Answer (score 0):

We generally use certain prepositions
On time= at the arranged time; not before, not after
In time= not late; with a Comfortable margin
Like in the sentences
I reached the office in time for the meeting
The meeting started on time.